# How to trigger OnNavigatedTo on the second/third tab in TabbedPage using Prism?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using the Prism. I have 4 tabs in my Tabbed Page: Home (static no OnNavigatedTo required, Activity (OnNavigatedTo required), Note (OnNavigatedTo required) and more page (OnNavigatedTo not required).

How do I trigger this OnNavigatedTo for this second and third tab? I tested this without the tab ie. using NavigationPage/ActivityList and the OnNavigatedTo working OK.

Found this code for code-behind for tabbed page BUT not sure what it does.

**CustomTabbedPage.xaml:**

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
<NavigationPage Title="Home" IconImageSource="home.png">
<x:Arguments> <local:HomePage/> </x:Arguments> 
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Activity" IconImageSource="activity.png">
<x:Arguments> <local:ActivityListPage/> </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Note" IconImageSource="note.png">
<x:Arguments> <local:ActivityListPage/> </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="More" IconImageSource="more.png">
<x:Arguments> <local:MorePage/> </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

**CustomTabbedPage.xaml.cs :**

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
  if (parameters.GetNavigationMode() == NavigationMode.New)
  {
    if (Children.Count == 1)
    {
      return;
    }
    for (var pageIndex = 1; pageIndex < Children.Count; pageIndex++)
    {
       var page = Children[pageIndex];
       (page?.BindingContext as INavigationAware)?.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
    }
  }
}
```

**app.xaml.cs**

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get(Constant.Setting_AccessToken, "")))
  {
    var result = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("CustomTabbedPage?selectedTab=HomePage");
  }
  else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get(Constant.Setting_UserEmail, "")) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get(Constant.Setting_Password, "")))
  {
    var result = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/LoginPage");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you inherit `INavigatedAware` ?

Comment: Yes I did in this page

Comment: you could try to update the prism version,it seems to fix the navigation in NavigationPage,refer to https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1164

Answer (score 2):

There is the concept of [knowing the active tab](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/working-with-tabbedpages.html#knowing-the-selected-tab) in prism

```
public class TabItemViewModel : BindableBase, IActiveAware
{
    // NOTE: Prism.Forms only sets IsActive, and does not do anything with the event.
    public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged;

    private bool _isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isActive, value, RaiseIsActiveChanged); }
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseIsActiveChanged()
    {
        IsActiveChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        if (IsActive)
        {
            // Do stuff here when tab is selected
        }
    }
}
```

so you can move your OnNavigatedTo code into the RaiseIsActiveChanged event.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but how about navigation parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, you didn't navigate to the tabs that aren't displayed.

When you Navigate to a TabbedPage, OnInitialized will be fired on the ViewModel of the TabbedPage, and all of its Children. This is where you would access the `INavigationParameters` to gather any context you may need to share between the tabs.

Assuming you have 3 tabs we'll call them TabA, TabB, and TabC, and let's assume you selected TabB as the tab that will display for the user, then the TabbedPage and TabB are the two pages that are NavigatedTo. Therefore only their ViewModel's will have OnNavigatedTo called.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for all your work on Prism. I'm reading dcpartners question a bit differently. I have the same situation I guess. I have NavigationPagea and 3 tabs, but when navigating from tab 1 to tab 2 using SelectTabAsync, only the OnNavigatedTo on the tabbedpage viewmoddel is getting called. The OnNavigated to on tab2 is not called. Only the RaiseIsActiveChanged() is getting called on tab2, hence I cannot pass navigation parameters in this situation.